# Import One component in another component using ng-content

Tags: angular

This is my Page where I am calling two components Panel and jointbutton:

```
<panel src="a" 
    data1="b" 
    data2="Student Id:"
    data3="Class:"
    data4="Roll No : " data5="Batch : ">
    <joint-button btnname="Edit" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" color="btn btn-primary"></joint-button>
    <joint-button btnname="Delete" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" color="btn btn-danger"></joint-button>
</panel>
```

This is my panel.html where i have used

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="custom5">
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="custom6">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
     </div>
 </div>
```

problem here is both jointbuttons are showing in first `<ng-content></ng-content>`

So my Question is::

- first of all Can we use `<ng-content></ng-content>` more than once. If yes then why doesn't it work.
- If we can't use `<ng-content></ng-content>` more than once then what is the solution for locating two components in two different places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-content` can take an attribute `select` which is a css selector of the element to include\select.

So this should work (i have not tried)

```
 <div class="custom5">
       <ng-content select="joint-button'[btnname=Edit]'"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="custom6">
        <ng-content select="joint-button'[btnname=Delete]'"></ng-content>
     </div>
```

Recently this was demo'ed in AngularConnect, see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YmnbGoh49U

Comment: It worked just a little syntax error in your code ::: select="joint-button'[btnname=Edit]".edited your code